# javascript split string on every other symbol

Tags: javascript, split

I have a string in the form of

```
":x1:y1:x2:y2x3:y3:...:"
```

and the keys and values Xn and Yn are arbitrary values so i can't use the length of the strings

i would like to split this string into a list or dictionary containing the key-value pairs

```
{"x1":"y1", "x2":"y2", ...}
```

I know that i can split the string on ":" and then put the resulting list back pairwise, but i was wondering if there was a way to do this in one go.

Comment: No, I don't think there is. Why would you use the same delimiter if you want them to be processed pair-wise?

Comment: i wouldn't but this is unfortunately the code i'm working with at the moment :p

Comment: AFAIK, you have to do the parse job yourself since its a format not widely used, so I don't think javascript will bother to provide anything convenient for that.

Comment: I think it's possible to construct a sentence `eval(str.replace(regexp).replace(regexp).replace(regexp))` to do it in one pass. (Of course the string should be safe to do that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var obj = (function(str){
  var result = {};

  str.replace(/([^\:]+)\:([^\:]+)/g, function($0, $1, $2){
    result[$1] = $2;
  });  

  return result;
})('x1:y1:x2:y2:x3:y3');
```

Comment: this did the trick. Thanks, i forgot you could use an "except" in your regexp match..