# javascript split but two words

Tags: javascript, split

Is there a way to split a string into 2 words using space as a delimiter? I know there is split(" ") but it is splitting it by one word. I want something like

```
var at = "this is not the end of the world boo";

at.somefunc(" ", 2)//returns ["this is", "not the", "end of", "the world", "boo"]
```

Comment: Asked and answered. Try a bit more research next time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782547/split-string-based-on-second-occurrence-of-delimiter-using-javascript

Comment: Not just that one @CollinD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947308/javascript-split-string-on-every-other-symbol now which one link merits the duplicate flag?